# How to click and swap a text in a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on a project where I want to click a button and change the text of button using jquery. Here is a structure of the button.

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

CSS:

```
  #button{
        position: relative;
        top: 14px;
        width: 190px;
        height: 57px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #ff5500;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000000;
        border-color: #ff5500;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
   document.getElementById('button').innerHTML='Click Me Again';
$('#button').on('click',function(){
   document.getElementById('button').innerHTML='Click Me';
});
 });
```

Now the thing is that once I click the button the text button changes and then if clicked again the text changes back. However, this happens only once. Is there something wrong here ? How do I make this continous, as in no matter how many times the button is clicked, the text keeps on changing ?Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is probably a better way to do it but to illustrate your problem, you are overwriting the click eventlistener on line 4. To get a similar effect, you would do something like

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
   if($(this).html() == "Click Me"){
       $(this).html("Click Me Again");
   }else{
       $(this).html("Click Me");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
   $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Click Me' ? 'Click Me Again' : 'Click Me');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Click Me' ? 'Click Me Again' : 'Click Me');
});
```

```js
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Click Me' ? 'Click Me Again' : 'Click Me');
});
```

```css
#button{
    position: relative;
    top: 14px;
    width: 190px;
    height: 57px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ff5500;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000000;
    border-color: #ff5500;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the change happens only once.

Comment: @ZubairAnwar - No it doesn't. Are you running the code example in the answer? It toggles repeatedly.

Comment: Well I tried the code before and it was showing once however I checked it again now after some changes in the markup, it works like a charm. Thanks for the shorthand solution and Apologies for the inconvenience !

Answer (score -1):

This should help you.

I didnt want to write stuff which others have already implemented:

http://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/

Comment: Nice just what I was looking for to optimize the above code, seems it can be done using CSS too. Thanks for the link !

Comment: Negative vote seriously!!
I wish whom so ever gave that, atleast explains why!